# Run custom shortcode twice in the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need help with a wordpress question.

I created a custom shortcode that retrieves a list of data inside a table with specific paramenter:

```
add_shortcode("archive", "archive_render");
function archive_render($atts) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "rientro" => "no",
    "year" => "",
), $atts));

global $wpdb;

$rientro == "si" ? $rientro = "yes" : "no";

$query = "SELECT event_name FROM wp_em_events WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM event_end_date) = ".$year." AND event_end_date < CURDATE()";
$pasts_event = $wpdb->get_col($query);

function get_pasts_event( $pasts_event ){

    foreach ( $pasts_event as $past_event_slug ) {
        $output .= "<li><a href='".get_site_url()."/eventi/".$past_event_slug."'>$past_event_slug</a></li>";
    }

    return $output;
}

$string = '[one_third last="'.$rientro.'" class="" id=""][accordian class="" id=""][toggle title="'.$year.'" open="no"]<ul>'.get_pasts_event($pasts_event).'</ul>[/toggle][/accordian][/one_third]';

echo do_shortcode( $string );
```

}

I want to retrieve all events that has past date compared with the current date.

If I add the shortcode twice in the page, only the first shortcode works and the page stop to display the rest of the content.

Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the rest of the page stopping or just the result of the second shortcode?  Have you enabled debug mode? There might be some errors in your code.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Shortcodes shouldn't output any content. Move the `get_posts_event` function outside of the shortcode and change echo to return.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress shortcode should return a string, not echoing it
let me re-arrange your code

```
function get_pasts_event( $pasts_event ){

    foreach ( $pasts_event as $past_event_slug ) {
        $output .= "<li><a href='".get_site_url()."/eventi/".$past_event_slug."'>$past_event_slug</a></li>";
    }

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode("archive", "archive_render");
function archive_render($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "rientro" => "no",
        "year" => "",
        ), $atts));

    global $wpdb;

    $rientro == "si" ? $rientro = "yes" : "no";

    $query = "SELECT event_name FROM wp_em_events WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM event_end_date) = ".$year." AND event_end_date < CURDATE()";
    $pasts_event = $wpdb->get_col($query);


    $string = '[one_third last="'.$rientro.'" class="" id=""][accordian class="" id=""][toggle title="'.$year.'" open="no"]<ul>'.get_pasts_event($pasts_event).'</ul>[/toggle][/accordian][/one_third]';

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. A question: why put outside the get_pasts_event() function?

Comment: because generally we should not declare function inside another function, although this is not produce error, and avoid re-declare that function when main function called 2x or more. As I know there are no scoping for global function.